# C# WPF PrintQueueException: PrintTicket provider failed to retrieve PrintCapabilities

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a C# WPF Desktop application on a tablet, which is connected by USB cable to a printer.
When I try to print a PDF report from my application to this specific printer, I get the following error:

```
{System.Printing.PrintQueueException: PrintTicket provider failed to retrieve PrintCapabilities. Win32 error: -2147467259
   at MS.Internal.Printing.Configuration.PTProvider.GetPrintCapabilities(MemoryStream printTicket)
   at System.Printing.PrintTicketManager.GetPrintCapabilitiesAsXml(PrintTicket printTicket)
   at System.Printing.PrintTicketManager.GetPrintCapabilities(PrintTicket printTicket)
   at System.Printing.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(PrintTicket printTicket)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.UpdatePrintableAreaSize()
   at System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.get_PrintableAreaWidth()
   at PulmOne.MiniBox2.Reporting.Controls.ReportProcessor.GetPrintableArea(Size& pageSize, Rect& printableArea)
   at PulmOne.MiniBox2.Reporting.Controls.ReportProcessor.<GetPageContentsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PulmOne.MiniBox2.Reporting.Controls.ReportProcessor.<GetDocumentAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PulmOne.MiniBox2.Reporting.Controls.ReportProcessor.<GenerateDocumentAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at PulmOne.MiniBox2.ReportsWpf.ReportWindow.<OnWindowLoaded>d__d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)}
```

I know the problem is in this code line:

```
{var dialog = new PrintDialog();
pageSize = new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight);}
```

IS there any way to solve this problem, so it'll work for all printers?

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck? I have the same issue

Comment: @David Nope, sorry...